# Pandas - Concat columns from different dataframes by index range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm relatively new here, been lurking. So, I have two simple dataframes (A & B).
I can't figure the most efficient way to concat these two dataframes as my data is > 200k of rows. Iterating with iterrows/itertuples is way too slow. These are entries from a log file.

DF A contains ordered entries of data (200k rows).

| Index | Entries |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 09:27:45 (adskflex) OUT: "87677ACDLT_2023_0F" |
| 1 | 09:27:46 (adskflex) OUT: "86917RVT_2018_0F" |
| ... | ... |
| 215758 | 10:17:56 (adskflex) IN: "87561RVT_2022_0F" |
| 215759 | 10:17:57 (adskflex) IN: "87561RVT_2022_0F" |

DF B contains unordered date entries.

| Index | Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 2943 | 9/25/2023 |
| 5116 | 9/25/2023 |
| ... | ... |
| 214660 | 11/23/2023 |
| 214898 | 11/23/2023 |

Need some help to prepend the dates into DF A while considering if the entry is within the index of date entry.

This is what I'd like to achieve.

| Index | Entries |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 9/25/2023 09:27:45 (adskflex) OUT: "87677ACDLT_2023_0F" |
| 1 | 9/25/2023 09:27:46 (adskflex) OUT: "86917RVT_2018_0F" |
| ... | ... |
| 215758 | 11/23/2023 10:17:56 (adskflex) IN: "87561RVT_2022_0F" |
| 215759 | 11/23/2023 10:17:57 (adskflex) IN: "87561RVT_2022_0F" |

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming date entries in DF B are in the 'Dates' column &  time entries in DF A are in the 'Entries' column, you can follow this steps:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming 'Dates' column in DF B is in datetime format

df_b['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df_b['Dates'])

# Extracting time from 'Entries' column in DF A

df_a['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['Entries'].str.extract('(\d+:\d+:\d+)')[0])

# Merging the dataframes based on the condition that time in DF A is betw date entries in DF B

merged_df = pd.merge_asof(df_a, df_b, left_on='Time', right_on='Dates')

# Combining date & time, then dropping unnecessary columns

merged_df['Combined'] = merged_df['Dates'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') + ' ' + merged_df['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

result_df = merged_df[['Combined', 'Entries']].copy()

# Drop intermediate columns if needed

result_df.drop(['Time', 'Dates', 'Combined'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Print the result_df

print(result_df)
```